# How to find out who controls the courier?

Tags: dota-2

So today, someone in my team decided to have fun by sending the courier to it's death every time it re spawned.

is there any way we can find out who is doing that ?

Comment: doesn't the courier icon on the bottom right change to show who's using it?  I'm not at home to take a screen shot or I'd try it.

Comment: @spartacus The icon shows up only is someone hits the deliver item to them button

Comment: ah, ok.  I guess that's no help then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the match, no.

But since you can see every Mouse Movement and which units gets selected by a player you can watch the replay after the Match and skip to the point where this happend and check every player on your team and see who did it. You can still report that player for some time after the match through the match details scoreboard on your User Profile.

Comment: cool, time to block him \o/

Comment: additionally u can watch which heroes stands still because he will most likely using the courier atm. even more so if both of you try to control him at the same time needing the full attention.